# Optaplanner :Error when displaying constraints scores

Tags: java, constraints, drools, optaplanner, kie

I use OtpaPlanner to optimize a vehicles routing extension. I have got hard and soft scores but when i try to display constraints Match details i got this message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException   
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.drools.DroolsScoreDirector.getConstraintMatchTotals(DroolsScoreDirector.java:98)    
at org.optaplanner.examples.common.business.SolutionBusiness.getConstraintMatchTotalList(SolutionBusiness.java:239)
```

the line of error can be this:  `kieSession.fireAllRules();`

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to call `scoredirector.setWorkingSolution(Solution)`. See section "5.5. Explaining the score" in the docs. This causes the kieSession to be null as Ocannaille's answer explains.

Comment: Yes it is true. now i can get the constraints scores

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is simply that `kieSession` is `null`. try :

```
if(kieSession != null) 
    kieSession.fireAllRules();
```

Without more information it's hard to debug this.